# how to handle download error in javascript, angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way to handle error generated when you are trying to download a file from the server, but the file does not exist and the server tries to return the error in json format but the front end is not able to handle the error as the browser has redirected to the download url. If you try to download with the ajax request, you are able to handle the error, but you don't get the default browser download progress.

```
downloadFile(): void {
   const downloadUrl = `${this._document.location.origin}${SharedService.manualProcessDownloadApi}/${this.selectedTaskId}/download?bulkDownload=false`;
   this._document.location.href = downloadUrl;
}
```